# Using Investpy access a unites states' company stock listed in germany

Tags: python

For example, getting real time data of amazon.com Inc. (WKN906866
ISINUS0231351067) listed in munich boerse.
The following works -

```
import investpy as inv
df = inv.get_stock_recent_data(stock='amzn', country='united states', interval='daily')
```

However, if country is set to `"germany"`, it given an error that `amzn` not found.

**Edit:**
Some more explanation before you down rate the question.

As suggested, the error is indeed expected, since amzn is not german company. However, it is also true that one can buy the same american company's stock via, e.g., Munich (or FRA or any german exchange) Boerse, which has a slightly different time-trend than american listed "AMZN" time-trend. My question is- how to access, e.g., "AMZN" time-trend available in Germany in euros?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://investpy.readthedocs.io/_api/stocks.html#investpy.stocks.get_stock_recent_data) the country parameter indicates 'the name of the country from where the stock is'. Amazon, being an American company, would not show up as a German stock in investpy and this is the source of your 'amzn not found' error.